# Bubble Sort through a doubly linkrd

Tags: c, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

am learning C with Kochans programming in C 4th edition.  I am on pointers, and my exercise is to write a pointer version of a sort function from a previous chapter.  This is a bubble sort.  I bit some code from a better coder for creating a doubly linked list (setting all the numbers as done in previous problems seemed pretty tedious).

In this sort, I am swapping the value.  Next, I will swap the entire nodes, though im unable to get this simpler one to work.  I tested the algorithm outside of the sort function and it worked except that it did not finish the job.  So I brought some bool variables into the game, but it exited the loop when upon reaching the first "true" result, so I created a function to test whether the list was sorted or not.  It enters an infinite loop, but I do not understand why.  There are other questions like mine, but all for C++, not C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct Node  {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* head; 

struct Node* GetNewNode(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode
        = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void InsertAtHead(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void InsertatEnd(int x)
{
struct Node* temp = head;

struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
}

void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("Forward: ");
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

bool testSort(void)
{
    struct Node* temp = head;

    bool test = false;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
   {
       if (temp->data > temp->next->data){
            return false;
            }
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    return true;
}

void sortList(void)
{
   struct Node* temp = head;
   int temp2;
    bool sorted = false;

   while(sorted == false){
    while(temp->next != NULL)
   {
       if (temp->data > temp->next->data){
            temp2 = temp->next->data;
            temp->next->data = temp->data;
            temp->data = temp2;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
   }
        sorted = testSort();
}
}


int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    int x;
    int array[16] = {34, -5, 5, 0, 12, 100, 56, 22, 44, -3, -9, 12, 17, 22, 6, 11};
    int count;

    struct Node* temp;

    for(count = 0; count < 16; ++count)
            InsertatEnd(array[count]);

    sortList();
    Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the variable head global in the book code?

Comment: no, there is no book code.  the exercise this cribs from used arrays

Comment: I am familiar with this book. The exercise uses an exchange sort rather than a bubble sort. Keep the code as simple as possible. No Booleans. No doubly-linked list. Just the simplest possible use of pointers.

Comment: I was planning to do all iterations.  value swap, node swap, then what i eventually realized what they were actually looking for in the book, the method you suggest.  im self taught so I feel like Ive got to carry a lot of water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I was able to figure it.  I did not need an extra function to test the list.  My issue was that temp, which had been set to head, did not reinitialize to evaluate the list from the beginning.  To determine this I added a printf statement for display the values of temp->data and temp->next->data, and realized the algorithm was only driving through a few of the numbers, so it was not exhaustively sorting.  The revised code is below.  The key was the temp = head statement inside the loop to reinitialize from the beginning.

```
void sortList(void)
{
   struct Node* temp = head;
   int temp2;
    bool sorted = false;

   while(sorted == false){
    sorted = true;
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
   {
       if (temp->data > temp->next->data){

            temp2 = temp->next->data;
            temp->next->data = temp->data;
            temp->data = temp2;
            sorted = false;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
   }
}
}
```